# Why is my for loop for getting a power set not working in R?

Tags: r

I want every single subset of inputset without the empty set in a single list. Why is my code not working?

```
inputSet <- c("ME4", "ME0", "ME12")
powerSet <- list()
for(counter in 1:length(inputSet)) {
powerSet <- append(powerSet, combn(inputSet, m = counter))
}
```

I end up getting ME4, ME0, ME12 in three separate cells in the list, repeated 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Call `combn` with `simplify=FALSE`.

```
for(counter in 1:length(inputSet)) {
    powerSet <- append(powerSet, combn(inputSet, m = counter, simplify=F))
}
```

By default `simplify=TRUE`, which means `combn` will give you an array:

```
> combn(inputSet, 2)
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "ME4" "ME4"  "ME0" 
[2,] "ME0" "ME12" "ME12"
```

And combining two arrays with `c` flattens the array out:

```
> c(combn(inputSet, 2), combn(inputSet, 2))
 [1] "ME4"  "ME0"  "ME4"  "ME12" "ME0"  "ME12" "ME4"  "ME0"  "ME4" 
[10] "ME12" "ME0"  "ME12"
```